# Text Change while loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the **loading screen text** several times. Like  **Loading**, **Collecting userdata**, **uploading picture**, **calculating** etc
I want to change these text after specific time .. How is this possible ?

Comment: Without code, It is not possible. Post some relevant code that you have tried.

Comment: use ajax call and when your call start start your loading and in success stop it

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are doing.

Comment: Please provide some code to show what you have tried, and try to narrow down your issue to a more specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

To change the status of your content you can just show random text to users depending on the type of content you're fetching.

> you don't have to `setTimeout` rather detect uploading percentage or
>   upload status and then accordingly set your data. Like for >90%, you
>   can say "Almost done" on 100% "moving file into folder" 'coz you know
>   PHP is doing something with your file at this time. similarly, use your creativity to generate other circumstances.

Here's a demo example

[working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbLsc81f/129/)

> Happy coding :)

Just in case Fiddle doesn't work I have also included the snippet.

```js
function onReady(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Do something after 1 second 
    document.getElementById('loading').innerHTML = "Collecting data !!";
  }, 500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Do something after 1 second 
    document.getElementById('loading').innerHTML = "Data collected. :)";
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    // Do something after 1 second 
    document.getElementById('loading').innerHTML = "Setting up the view for you...";
  }, 1400);

  setTimeout(function() {
    // Do something after 1 second 
    document.getElementById('loading').innerHTML = "Almost done...";
  }, 1900);


  var intervalID = window.setInterval(checkReady, 3000);

  function checkReady() {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] !== undefined) {
      window.clearInterval(intervalID);
      callback.call(this);
    }
  }
}

function show(id, value) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = value ? 'block' : 'none';
}

onReady(function() {
  show('page', true);
  show('loading', false);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #FFF url("http://i.imgur.com/KheAuef.png") top left repeat-x;
  font-family: "Brush Script MT", cursive;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}

#page {
  display: none;
}

#loading {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.5);
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnyxU.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <h1>The standard Lorem Ipsum passage</h1>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div id="loading">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: Hi, could you give an example of how to detect page load percentage, rather than using setTimeout()? So while the page is loading, depending on how far along the page load is, display specific text. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @anthonyCam sorry, I wasn't around for some time. I hope you have your answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default text that will have maximum opacity and will be shown middle of the page. Idea is like when you have completed any activity change the text.

```
<div id="loader">
  Loading
</div>
```

in jquery

```
//when loading done change
$("#loader").text("Collecting userdata");
//when Collecting userdata done
$("#loader").text("uploading picture");
```

if you are using ajax. you can do like

```
 $.ajax({url: "url", success: function(result){
       $("#loader").text("Collecting userdata");
    }});
$.ajax({url: "url", success: function(result){
    $("#loader").text("uploading picture");
    }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **css** and **jquery** for loader

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/ewecopmn/6/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="loading"> </div>
<span>something loading above me</span>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(".loader").fadeIn();
```

**CSS:**

```
.loading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:9999;
    text-align: center;
    background: url('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/10ixuZLPPWgFkm1fEIT1p0SxkIbwLMmxn3XN1hQTUA=s207-p-no') no-repeat center center;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

> In above example I use simple image you can use different animated
>   text images in css
>
> For text image loader Click -> :
>   http://preloaders.net/en/letters_numbers_words

Answer (score 0):

You could set timers for each stage. So after 5seconds the first stage hits, 10 seconds second stage and so on.